# I upgraded SVN::Core via CPAN and now git-svn doesn't recognise http:// URLs

Tags: svn, git, cpan

I was trying to update version of Subversion used by `git svn` and so I ran the following command.

```
> cpan SVN::Core
```

It appeared to work; however, now `git svn` doesn't recognise HTTP URLs!

```
> git svn rebase
Bad URL passed to RA layer: Unrecognized URL scheme for 'http://<...>' at /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 2265
```

I've tried it on `svn://` URLs and it works okay.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm running OS X 10.6 and using MacPorts for git, subversion, perl, and cpan.

Answer (score 6):

SVN::Core depends on it's own version of subversion (which it configures and builds) for 
providing SVN capabilities.

I had the same problem and found out that SVN has a dependency on libneon for http and https transport 
support.

I installed libneon-dev and re-ran the install for SVN::Core and it worked.

Comment: This was the worst experience I'd ever had with cpan. Thanks so much for figuring this out.

Comment: I have `neon-0.30.0` installed and `git-svn version 1.8.4.2 (svn 1.7.3)` installed but I'm still getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: @JaKXz I know this is old, but the headers are in the neon-devel package, not the neon package, which is runtime only