# Bad URL passed to RA layer: Unrecognized URL scheme

Tags: git, perl, svn, git-svn

I installed subversion 1.9 on RHEL 7.3 x86_64 VM. Below is the output of svn version.

```
[root@<hostname> ~]# svn --version
svn, version 1.9.7 (r1800392)
   compiled Aug 10 2017, 21:36:06 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

Copyright (C) 2017 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - using serf 1.3.8 (compiled with 1.3.7)
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme

The following authentication credential caches are available:

* Plaintext cache in /root/.subversion
* Gnome Keyring
* GPG-Agent
```

I have installed git 2.9. Below is the output of git version.

```
[root@<hostname> ~]# git --version
git version 2.9.5
```

Any git svn operation leading to the below error.

```
[root@<hostname> codebase]# git svn fetch
Bad URL passed to RA layer: Unrecognized URL scheme for 'http://<IP>:<PORT>/svn/trunk/Automation/UCM' at /usr/local/git/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 144.
```

Below is the perl version.

```
[root@<hostname> ~]# perl --version

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux

Copyright 1987-2013, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Have installed Alien SVN using the command cpan SVN::core and have also installed subversion perl binaries.

Googled but couldnt get it to work. Tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13865154/2663585) but no luck.
Can someone please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you initiated a svn repo yet?

Comment: @xxfelixxx, Yup i initially ran the "git svn init <SVN_URL>" which ran successfully. And then when i ran the "git svn fetch", i ended up getting the error which i have posted in the question.

Comment: @ikegami, no i replaced the 'actual http URL' with <SVN_URL>.

Comment: Have you set up a different svn repo and set it up to be the remote of this git svn repo?

Comment: Precisely, i have a SVN repo running over http, and initialize it using 'git svn init http://IP:PORT/svn/trunk/Automation/UCM', then i set the remote using the command 'git remote add origin http://IP:PORT/svn/trunk/Automation/UCM' and then do a 'git svn fetch'. The last command is failing with the error which i have posted in the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571944/git-svn-unrecognized-url-scheme-error

Comment: I upgraded git to the latest version, which is 2.17, and still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The cpan SVN::Core installation uses the SERF libraries (for HTTP scheme handling) only if it finds them.
Try and install the SERF-dev library:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libserf-dev
```

then re-install (re-build) SVN::Core:

```
$ cpan
...
cpan[1]> install SVN::Core
```

you should see this `configure` output:

```
configure: serf library configuration via pkg-config
checking for serf-2 library... no
checking for serf-1 library... yes
checking serf library version... 1.3.8
checking serf version is suitable... yes
checking was serf enabled... yes
```