# Jenkins - How to use : git-svn command

Tags: git, jenkins, svn

I would like to know how to use the command `git svn clone Path/To/Svn Path/To/Dir` on a Jenkins slave.

---

The problem is the username and password used by the master to launch the command. It seems that the master is using a "SYSTEM" user with no password. Here's the output :

---

```
C:\jenkins\workspace\Tests>git svn clone Path/To/Svn Path/To/Dir 
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/jenkins/workspace/Tests/.git/
Authentication realm: <Server> CollabNet Subversion Repository
Password for 'SYSTEM': 
Authentication realm: <Server> CollabNet Subversion Repository
Username: Use of uninitialized value $ret in chomp at 
/mingw64/share/perl5/Git.pm line 596.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at 
/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Prompt.pm line 20.
Password for '': 
Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 
'Path/To/Svn': Unexpected server error 500 'Internal Server Error' on 
'Path/To/Svn' at /mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 148.
```

---

That user has no right in my SVN server. I've tried adding `--username 'username' --password 'password'` on the command or to change the `~/.subversion/servers` file to save the authentification, but it didn't worked.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks.

Edit : Path/To/Svn is a network link : `https://`.

Comment: When you clone `Path/To/Svn` do you mean that the repository is accessible locally, via a mounted filesystem? Make sure the FS is mounted and the repository is accessible. If not you need to access it over the network using `svn://` or `http://` protocols.

Comment: It's a network link like https://. I've edited my question, Thanks.

Comment: Try `git svn clone https://username:password@server/path`

Comment: Tried it and didn't worked ... the error output is : `Bad URL passed to RA layer`

Comment: Most probably an issue with too old SVN: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13865154/7976758

Comment: My git-svn version seems to be recent : `git-svn version 2.17.0.windows.1 (svn 1.9.7)`

Comment: @Emile did you find the answer of the above question?